# Removing Array from Subdocument in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to remove an array of a subdocument from a MongoDB. Here you can see the dataset:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5971cd685369fa57f41a6af3"),
    "msgtyp" : 1,
    "number" : "201700005",
    "name" : "name",
    "status" : null,
    "position" : [ 
        {
            "pos" : 1,
            "number" : "9874326",
            "value" : "art 123",
        }, 
        {
            "pos" : 2,
            "number" : "125124",
            "value" : "art 321",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to remove the the whole array entry from `"pos" : 1` according to `pos` and `number`. The expected document should be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5971cd685369fa57f41a6af3"),
    "msgtyp" : 1,
    "number" : "201700005",
    "name" : "name",
    "status" : null,
    "position" : [ 
        {
            "pos" : 2,
            "number" : "125124",
            "value" : "art 321",
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the following code:

```
exports.delete_position = function(req, res) {
  auftrag.remove(
    {
      "number": req.body.number, 
      "position.pos": req.body.pos
    }, function(err, position){
    if(err)
      res.status(400).send(err);
    res.status(200).json(position);
  });
};
```

Unfortunately the array entry can not be removed. Can you tell me how to remove this entry?

Would it be better/best practice not to use `pos` and `number` to remove the entry and use the `_id` instead?

Thanks!

Comment: the object contained pos=1, always is the first array?

Comment: No just in this case. It also can be on another position for example if there are four positions (pos=1, pos=3, pos=4, pos=5) and a user want to remove pos=3 it is the second position but pos=4.